# Upload base64 file into GCS using signedURL

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, postman, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to upload **base64** file/image into **Google cloud storage** using the **signed URL**. My server side code (NodeJS) is something like this:

```
let {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

storage = new Storage({
  projectId,
  keyFilename: gcloudServiceAccountFilePath,
});

function generateSignedUrl(){
const options = {
      version: 'v4',
      action: 'write',
      expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
      //contentType: 'application/octet-stream'
    };
}

const [url] = await storage.bucket(gcloudBucket)
      .file(`${fileRelativePath}`).getSignedUrl(options);

return url;
}
```

Now when I try with POSTMAN with below configuration,

```
Request: PUT
URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/my-signed-url.. //generated from above code
Headers:
  x-goog-acl: 'public-read'
  Content-Type: 'image/jpeg'
Body:
  raw : 'base64-file-conent'
```

My uploaded file in GCS stays as base64 and file size is also different as you can see in the storage.

[image]

1st image is directly uploaded into GCS with drag & drop.

2nd image is uploaded with POSTMAN

Not sure if I'm missing something while generating signed-url or any headers while uploading file through postman.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference in the Object sizes uploaded to the Google Cloud Storage is actually the difference in the Metadata of the Object. When you upload the image Object with POSTMAN by using REST APIs, the API header is added as part of the image's metadata. This [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-upload) clearly states that    “the Cloud Storage stores these headers as part of the object's metadata”.

The [first line of the Object metadata Introduction](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#introduction) also confirms that Objects stored in Cloud Storage have metadata associated with them.  Hence, the API headers are added as the Metadata of your Image object and consequently increase the Size of the Object.

Image Objects uploaded via the Console do not have Object metadata, except [they are explicitly set](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_metadata).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the issue is file stays in base64 from so I can not get the preview of it.

Comment: The Google Cloud Storage does not decode Base64 encoded files. If you upload an encoded Base64 image to the GCS bucket, it will not be decoded.

Comment: You can use base64  encoded string as values of image source in [HTML  or CSS  background](https://www.base64-image.de/tutorial) to review it.